# What does the Helmholtz Free Energy in thermodynamics signify? What is its physical significance?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, kinetic-theory

When we say internal energy, we're talking about the total kinetic energy of the particles in the system (ideal gas). So, when they say internal energy increased I imagine the particles moving faster (number of particles is kept constant), then how can I visualise or understand Helmholtz free energy?

Comment: [In thermodynamics, the Helmholtz free energy (or Helmholtz energy) is a thermodynamic potential that measures the useful work obtainable from a closed thermodynamic system at a constant temperature (isothermal).](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_free_energy)

Comment: @Farcher You omitted the constraint of constant volume.

Comment: @ChetMiller It was not me, rather the quote was taken from the linked page.

Comment: @Farcher Sorry, my mistake.